# IAM authentication to connect with any SQL client to Amazon RDS for MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I can connect to the MySQL RDS database using IAM authentication from the SQL command line tool. But the same I need to achieve connections with SQL clients like DBeaver or some other clients. I don't have the provision of passing tokens in SQL client.

This document explains connecting RDS using MySQL workbench/j but I am unable to download the MySQL workbench/j due to a forbidden error. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-iam-authentication-to-connect-with-sql-workbenchj-to-amazon-aurora-mysql-or-amazon-rds-for-mysql/

Could someone help me in connecting RDS using IAM authentication from an SQL client?

Answer (score 1):

Create a default connection with the host, username and save the profile without entering a password. After that:

```bash
export TOKEN="$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token \
--hostname <hostname> \
--port <port> \
--region <region> \
--username <db-user-name>)"
open -a "DBeaver.app" --args -con "driver=mysql|name=<ProfileName>|connect=true|database=<DatabaseName>|password=$TOKEN|create=false"
```

And also you can add custom driver to dbeaver like the AWS JDBC:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mysql-jdbc?tab=readme-ov-file#using-the-driver-with-a-database-client-dbeaver

Answer (score 0):

In fact you could use the aws rds command to generate each time a new token to use as your password to authenticate the database. But since you want to do it with deaver, looks like its available (https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/AWS-Credentials/) but only in Enterprise edition (not the community edition)

[image]

Comment: Exactly, I have gone through the Dbeaver document. Do you aware of any other clients?

Comment: I made a lot of research but sadly, today there is no other clients that have this feature, hope it will come soon in the community <3

Answer (score -2):

If you're going to use DBeaver
The proper connection details :

- Server Host: Endpoint address
- Port: 3306
- Database: DB name
- User name: Database master username
- Password: Database master password

1
[image: 2]

2
[image: 1]

Comment: with RDS IAM authentication, we don't want to provide passwords instead we generate tokens and use that to connect the database.

Comment: @vignesh I'ts always recommended to use tokens instead of clear password

Comment: yeah, But I am unable to use tokens in SQL clients like DBeaver or SQL workbench. is there any option to use tokens in SQL clients?

Comment: So if you want to use Token this command will help you with that :  `aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $yourhostname --port 3306 --username $IAMUSER --region=$REGION`

Comment: if you want to download mysql workbench : [Download Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) , 
This process will help you through this. [how-to-connect-aws-rds-mysql](https://petri.com/how-to-connect-aws-rds-mysql/)

Comment: I have tried this SQL workbench before, but it has the option to input only the password not the token generated.